# How do you secure your PC and Wifi at a shared office/co-working space like WeWork?

Tags: network

I'm fairly good with PC's but no expert.  I'm at a WeWork (coworking) and connecting to WeWork's wifi network.  There are a bunch of tech startups, so quite a number of people who could potentially breach a vulnerable PC/network.  What precautions can I take to keep them off my computer?

VPN? Encrypted router?  What would the smart things to do be that would at least make it very tough to be hacked?  Change my passwords to some crazy string like S$jfaF134$*jf! ?

Comment: Wifi won't let them on to your computer. They might be able to see your traffic and gain access to your online accounts though.

Comment: What you have is basically a scenario that's the same as using a coffee shop wifi. There are many questions here and many guides online for securing your devices in such a scenario.