# Best Security measures for non-IT pro to take when at risk of hackers?

Tags: windows, vulnerability

I work at a WeWork and am surrounded by about 5 different IT / coding type of companies.  They apparently hacked me somehow, I don't know how, whether it was bluetooth or using WeWork wifi, or maybe the screen sharing app used to control monitors WeWork uses or the Papercut print client. Somehow they were on my PC, as if they were controlling it (like a screensharing remote access app).  They apparently thought it was funny, messing with stupid stuff like my volume settings, moving files on my desktop, writing in a Word document.  However, I'm not playing... I want everything on lockdown but I'm no pro.

What steps would an IT pro do if they were in a shared office environment to put their PC on lockdown?

Things I did:

- Changed all my passwords to strong passwords, and am keeping different passwords for my important points of entry.  Ex. different passwords for home router, Microsoft 365, Google, etc.
- Started connecting to the network by ethernet cable.  Leaving Wifi and bluetooth turned off.
- Connect to VPN.
- Started using Norton 360, I believe Windows Defender still runs too.

What else should I do?

- fresh install of Windows?
- get an encrypted router to connect to Wework ethernet?
- switch to Mac?
- stop letting Google Chrome store passwords?  I mean, if they can access my PC and see the screen all they have to do is go into Chrome settings they can expose all my passwords immediately.

What steps would you recommend?  I have a surface pro (5th gen) running Windows 10 Pro.

The original hacking occurred almost 2 months ago at which time I did the 'things I did'.. and believed I kicked them off?  I'm not so sure, I've been using the ethernet cable & vpn for about 2 months with no issues.  Just the other day I started having this problem, when I would come into the office and plug in and start-up, it would not connect to the network automatically.  I couldn't figure it out, I checked my ethernet connections they seemed good.  I went into network adapters, disabled/enabled and internet works perfectly.  Have had to do this 2 days in a row now every time I boot up.  I have a friend in IT I was telling about this yesterday she said it sounds like they are still on my PC or they are 
'snooping' and that's why I have to disable/enable my router, she says I'm 'kicking them off' most likely.  Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: You have to break the whole network set-up in order to fully ensure detachment, generally speaking this can take a minute. But because this is a regular joke of one other employee, you can create some separated "place" on the level you are. Interesting: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Chadwick3/publication/242152206/figure/fig5/AS:298643383963675@1448213539792/Combining-permissions-with-the-role-hierarchy-to-determine-what-can-be-delegated.png

Comment: Looks like a continuation of this problem?: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214609/how-do-you-secure-your-pc-and-wifi-at-a-shared-office-co-working-space-like-wewo

Comment: The reason for this question is the current network issue. There is no reason to think that network connectivity problems are the result of hackers. They sound like network connectivity problems. When you see hoofprints, think "horses" not "zebras".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do a bit more to reduce your attack surface. While you have already done a lot of things to improve your situation which is good, unfortunately you have absolutely no control of your physical network which is generally the source of most hacking attempts. This is compounded even further by the fact that that it is a shared network and you have no idea what is happening on that network. For all you know, someone sitting a few desks down could be [Wiresharking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) (eavesdropping) all your network traffic.

So with that said and assuming you are not experiencing any problems on your home network, here are a few steps I would advise you to take to start with.

1. First off, back up all your data and personal files, VERY IMPORTANT to do this properly as you don't want to lose any data.
2. Do a fresh install of Windows 10. This is an important step because it may well be that you have some form of malware on your machine that you don't know of and your AV is not detecting it.
3. After doing a clean install of Windows, install the latest updates and drivers for your PC and then try using Bitdefender Total Security. Norton 360 has a very low detection score and I would strongly advise against using it. The firewall on your PC is the very last line of defense against hackers and malware/spyware/ransomware etc. You want to make sure you have the best level of protection available to you.
4. After installing your AV, go to your network adapter settings and change your DNS to 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare) or 9.9.9.9 (Quad9). If you don't know how to do this, Google is your friend.
5. Download and run [Shutup10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or something similar. It reduces Microsoft bloatware and improves the security on your PC by disabling a number of hacker friendly breach points.
6. Since you use Chrome, you should then install a few security extensions on it. The most popular ones are:

   - Cookie Autodelete
   - UBlock Origin
   - HTTPS Everywhere (EFF)
   - Privacy Badger (EFF)
7. Disable anything you can that involves IoT connections. Try not to use them at all. If you do have to use something over WiFi or Bluetooth, disable the adapters straight away after using them.
8. Grab an external USB drive, encrypt it with a strong password, and then install an offline password manager like [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/) on it for all your passwords. It is a bit tedious to start with but once you have everything in it, it is very easy to manage and maintain. Then, when you need to provide usernames, passwords or anything sensitive, you will simply right-click, copy-paste them into the appropriate places when working online. Once this is done, get rid of all your Google passwords and turn all that kind of stuff off.
9. Add two step authentication for all your online accounts. If you use a mobile phone, grab something like [FreeOTP](https://freeotp.github.io/) and use it for everything you can.
10. Keep using your commercial VPN to connect to the outside world when you are in the WeShare office. Most VPN provider's also have an extension available for your web browser. If so, grab it and use it as well.
11. If you are interested in going down the path of setting up your own router, then grab something that has the capability of installing third party firewall firmware like [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/), [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), or [Tomato](https://advancedtomato.com/). If you are really keen, you could go all out and setup a [PFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/) box!

There are many other things that can be added to this list but this is a solid starting point.

Comment: 1. No I am not using any router.  I have a Surface Pro (5th gen) hooked up to Surface Dock with an ethernet cable in surface dock going straight to wall jack provided by WeWork.  At home I use my Verizon Fios routher, it uses WPA2-Personal encryption.

2. I use Private Tunnel VPN.  I just started using Norton 360 which also has a VPN, so I guess I"ve paid for 2 options, but figure I have to use 1.

3. I have my own printer, connected by Wifi to the WeWork network.  WeWork also has their printers, which I access by the network and their Papercut client until my free prints are gone.

Comment: Would doing something like switching to a Verizon mobile hotspot (they have 5g where I am) would be more secure than hardwired connection to Wework network?

Comment: Absolutely! Getting off that shared network would be most ideal. However, you still need to consider the possibility that your actual devices have been compromised. Switching networks will not help you if you already have malware on your machine. Follow the steps I provided and see how you go. Also, do you have an alternative way of getting your printing done? One option would be to drop your files onto a USB and physically print them from the USB rather than connecting to the WiFi device on the WeWork network.